# Converting CSV to JSON in Python: how to get rid of extra brackets

Tags: python, json, csv

After a lot of work, I have code that is creating the JSON output I need when running a CSV through it.

Here is a sample of the CSV:

insert_topic,Academic Program,class | classroom | (course materials)~3....

insert_topic,Academic Quality,"((learning outcomes)~3 | (learning expectations)~3 ) | learning ...

insert_topic,Academic Support,(available teacher)~3 | (available faculty)~3...

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import json
from itertools import groupby

csvfile = open('TIQ_dict_topics.csv', 'r').readlines()
jsonfile = open('Topics.json', 'w')
 
r = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
data = [dict(d) for d in r]
groups = []
 
for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['label'], r['operation'])):
    groups.append({
        "operation": k[1],
        "topic": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['operation']} for d in list(g)]
        })

out=json.dumps(groups[:], indent=4)

jsonfile.write(out)
```

Here is the output:

```
[
    {
        "operation": "insert_topic",
        "topic": [
            {
                "label": "Academic Program",
                "query": "lots here..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "operation": "insert_topic",
        "topic": [
            {
                "label": "Academic Quality",
                "query": "..."
            }
        ]
    },
```

Everything is great EXCEPT there are square brackets that are not necessary and which I have to remove in order to use this file in the program I'm using it for. (The square brackets in bold.)

[
{
"operation": "insert_topic",
"topic": **[**
{
"label": "Academic Program",
"query": "lots here..."
}
**]**
},

What part of the code is writing those square brackets and is there an easy way to just get rid of those without rewriting everything?

I have tried every CSV to JSON solution on the internet. This is the closest I've gotten to the structure I need. I have not used JSON much before this project so I'm still learning what parts of JSON code do what.

Comment: If `g` always has one element, you can just remove that list comprehension and use `g` instead. If not, you could add a check to see if `len(g) > 1`, and either use a list comprehension or not based on it.

Comment: (Gonna preface this with a disclaimer that I'm pretty novice when it comes to Python.) The columns that are supposed to be grouped under "topic" will always be the same two variables, "label" and "query". I *think* that's what is being called by g. I can't do a length check for some reason in the code.  I get this error: "TypeError: object of type 'itertools._grouper' has no len()".

Comment: My mistake, you can use `len(list(g))`. However, if that is the case, try using this line: `"topic": {k: v for k, v in list(g).items() if k not in ['operation']}`

Comment: Huh. Strangely enough apparently there's nothing in g?? len(list(g)) is telling me 0.

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question and include the sample of CSV (as text) that generates the JSON you included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing some input CSV (and maybe more than a little) I cannot say for sure what good itertools.groupby does.  I don't see you sorting the rows before using it, [from the documentation on groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

Do you know that CSV has already sorted by `(label, operation)` before you open it?

I'd like to suggest the following changes to your program.

Oh, and I assume your CSV looks something like:

```
operation,label,query
op1,label1,query1
op1,label1,query2
op1,label2,query3
op2,label3,query4
op2,label4,query5
op2,label3,query6
```

You can create a DictReader on the file directly, no need to readlines then pass that list to DictReader:

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = list(reader)
```

`list(reader)` turns the iterator into an actual list of dicts; not strictly necessary, but it'll help to have a list if/when you need to debug it, like:

```py
print(rows)
# [
#     {"operation": "op1", "label": "label1", "query": "query1"},
#     {"operation": "op1", "label": "label1", "query": "query2"},
#     {"operation": "op1", "label": "label2", "query": "query3"},
#     {"operation": "op2", "label": "label3", "query": "query4"},
#     {"operation": "op2", "label": "label4", "query": "query5"},
#     {"operation": "op2", "label": "label3", "query": "query6"},
# ]
```

With that list of input rows (dicts), iterate and directly create your JSON structure then open the output file and dump it:

```py
data = []
for row in rows:
    obj = {
        "operation": row["operation"],
        "topic": {
            "label": row["label"],
            "query": row["query"],
        },
    }

    data.append(obj)

with open("output.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Given that input CSV I shared above, I get:

```json
[
    {
        "operation": "op1",
        "topic": { "label": "label1", "query": "query1" }
    },
    {
        "operation": "op1",
        "topic": { "label": "label1", "query": "query2" }
    },
    {
        "operation": "op1",
        "topic": { "label": "label2", "query": "query3" }
    },
    {
        "operation": "op2",
        "topic": { "label": "label3", "query": "query4" }
    },
    {
        "operation": "op2",
        "topic": { "label": "label4", "query": "query5" }
    },
    {
        "operation": "op2",
        "topic": { "label": "label3", "query": "query6" }
    }
]
```

I only see you needing groupby if you want similar objects grouped under a common key in the final JSON, like:

```json
{
    "op1@@label1": [
        {
            "operation": "op1",
            "topic": { "label": "label1", "query": "query1" }
        },
        {
            "operation": "op1",
            "topic": { "label": "label1", "query": "query2" }
        }
    ],
    "op1@@label2": [
        {
            "operation": "op1",
            "topic": { "label": "label2", "query": "query3" }
        }
    ],
    "op2@@label3": [
        {
            "operation": "op2",
            "topic": { "label": "label3", "query": "query4" }
        },
        {
            "operation": "op2",
            "topic": { "label": "label3", "query": "query6" }
        }
    ],
    "op2@@label4": [
        {
            "operation": "op2",
            "topic": { "label": "label4", "query": "query5" }
        }
    ]
}
```

To get that, I recommend first defining a *key function* (like your lambda, but now defined for other functions to use):

```py
def key_func(row):
    return (row["operation"], row["label"])
```

Now, following the documentation, sort the rows before grouping:

```py
rows.sort(key=key_func)
grouped_iter = groupby(rows, key=key_func)
```

I'll redefine data to be an object/dict.  Each grouping key will have an array/list of the objects we created earlier.  Then, iterate on `grouped_iter`:

```py
data = {}
for key, grouped_rows in grouped_iter:
    grouped_list = []
    for row in grouped_rows:
        obj = {
            "operation": row["operation"],
            "topic": {
                "label": row["label"],
                "query": row["query"],
            },
        }

        grouped_list.append(obj)

    data["@@".join(key)] = grouped_list
```

Then open the output JSON file and dump, like above.

You can view the complete code with input CSV and output JSONs [here](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/403c4ae9b5ab53bc2fc91a6ea9e9a55c).

Comment: Thank you this seems to be working! Apologies for not including the CSV data originally (I posted at the end of a long work day). You guessed correctly for how the CSV data looks. You're correct that I didn't need the groupby. And I don't remember now why I added the readlines at some point, but I had been experimenting with different code all day to try and get the grouping/hierarchy correct and at some point in time DictReader didn't work unless I added readlines. Thanks again!